# GDB assembler debugging

Tags: assembly, gdb, binaryfiles, elf

I have to do a some binary analyses for a class, and I am stuck on one of the programs. When I set some breakpoints and disas, I see that it looks like this :

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x080484e2 <+0>:    push   %ebp
    0x080484e3 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
    0x080484e5 <+3>:    sub    $0x48,%esp
    0x080484e8 <+6>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
    0x080484eb <+9>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
    0x080484f0 <+14>:   sub    %eax,%esp
    0x080484f2 <+16>:   cmpl   $0x1,0x8(%ebp)
    0x080484f6 <+20>:   jg     0x8048504 <main+34>
    0x080484f8 <+22>:   movl   $0x7,(%esp)
 => 0x080484ff <+29>:   call   0x804833c <exit@plt>
    0x08048504 <+34>:   mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048507 <+37>:   add    $0x4,%eax
    0x0804850a <+40>:   mov    (%eax),%eax
    0x0804850c <+42>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
    0x0804850f <+45>:   call   0x804832c <atoi@plt>
    0x08048514 <+50>:   mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
    0x08048517 <+53>:   cmpl   $0xd,-0x10(%ebp)
    0x0804851b <+57>:   jne    0x804853b <main+89>
    0x0804851d <+59>:   lea    -0x38(%ebp),%eax
    0x08048520 <+62>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
    0x08048523 <+65>:   call   0x8048414 <makebuf>
    0x08048528 <+70>:   lea    -0x38(%ebp),%eax
    0x0804852b <+73>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
    0x0804852f <+77>:   movl   $0x804863b,(%esp)
 ** 0x08048536 <+84>:   call   0x804831c <printf@plt>
    0x0804853b <+89>:   movl   $0x1,(%esp)
    0x08048542 <+96>:   call   0x804833c <exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

(I've edited in the stars next to the location of call to printf@plt).
What it looks like to me is a program that has a call to exit(), then builds a string, then prints that string out, and then does another exit(). I think that if I can bypass this first call to exit(), it will print me out the answer to the challenge. Is the right way to do this to set the location where the call occurs to execute NOP? If so, what is the opcode for NOP? I've tried setting to 0x0 and 0x00000000. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If this is homework related, you should tag the question as `Homework`.  It will still be evaluated.

Comment: you say, 'it looks to me'.  instead, you should say, 'when I single step it does....'

Answer (score 3):

look at the lines

```
0x080484f2 <+16>:   cmpl   $0x1,0x8(%ebp)
0x080484f6 <+20>:   jg     0x8048504 <main+34>
```

and ascertain how you can get the program to skip the first exit - no need for injection

Comment: I don't really know any assembly. I tried going from the breakpoint that I am at and doing a jump to a further instruction, but I get a seg fault. Should I maybe insert a break before those two lines and jump over all of those instructions?

Comment: I assume that since this is 'for a class', that deducing what the code is doing is the purpose of the exercise.  So, you'll need to learn the appropriate assembly to successfully complete the assignment.

Comment: I'm clearly trying to learn here, and not just asking for the answer... Is there a way to edit only the parameters of the instructions in gdb?

Comment: The solution to your homework is (unfortunately) given in another answer (see Arash Thr)

Comment: Printing that variable doesn't give the answer. I'm assuming because it hasn't been set or assigned the correct value yet. I tried setting the location where $ebp is stored to a different value, but the program ends with the same results. Is there no good way to modify the values of the function parameters without rewriting the entire instruction line?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't necessarily exit, because of this line :

```
cmpl   $0x1,0x8(%ebp)
```

In this line, the program checks the value of the first argument to this function with one and if it greater, jumps.
Also, if you want to see the format of printf in here, you can enter `printf "%s", 0x804863b` in gdb.
**Update :**
If this procedure is main, then `0x8($ebp)` contains so-called argc, which is the number of inputs of your program. So what you need to do is when you're running the program give it input. like `./a.out blah`.
Also you can check this value by entering `x/2wx $esp` in gdb.

Comment: So, I need to change it to compare with some number other than 1? or manipulate the value passed as the argument? How can that be achieved?

Comment: Give it input while starting the program. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to just NOP out the calls to exit.  You might be able to get away with it this time, but in both calls to exit they are placing the exit code onto the stack prior to the call.  Depending on the rest of the program those stack values may or may not be used.

So your options would be to either NOP out both the MOV and the CALL or to force the jumps to always go the way you want.

Or the best way is to figure out exactly what parameters make it do what you want.

Also the standard NOP opcode for x86 is 0x90.

Comment: Well, since you said that using NOPing out calls isn't a good way to manipulate the running program, what would be a good way to force that comparison to always result in a jump? Is there a way to make it always return true?

Comment: you can replace a jg with a jmp you just have to make sure your math and instruction sizes line up.
Or you could just nop out the jmp the mov and the call. so that the stack doesn't get altered.
In this specific case you could probably get away with noping only the call, but don't get in the habit of doing it without making sure the stack will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about homework then you should know what is allowed to do.

If patching is allowed, then the best way would be to change the opcode from jg to jng, you will have to look in the intel manuals to see what will have to be changed, but it will generally be one byte.

If patching is not allowed then you will have to find the function that will set the variable that is being compared and figure out how to make that function set it to something else.

Comment: I am allowed to do anything that will get me what I need. I guess I will do some research on patching. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

0x90 is a NOP instruction for x86.  Therefore 0x90 is one NOP instruction, 0x9090 is two NOP instructions, 0x90909090 would be 4 NOP instructions.

Carefully check the length of the `call 0x804833c` instruction.  I don't believe that it is 4 bytes long.